# Tkinter elements and pagination

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pagination

I have been working on an simple program for making folder backups. The console version works flawless, but I have encountered one problem while working on Tkinter version. I want to display buttons in grid like manner, each button will be responsible for backup of given folder and I would like to limit 20 buttons per "page". I manage to create simple pagination, which works only when increment the page number. When I try do decrease the page number, console prompts me an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Rzeczy Mariusza\Python\Backup_manager\main_gui.py", line 83, in 
    go_back_event_handler self.show_avaliable_directories()
  File "D:\Rzeczy Mariusza\Python\Backup_manager\main_gui.py", line 72, in 
    show_avaliable_directories
  self.active_directories[i].place(x=_x, y=_y)
  File "D:\Programy\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2019, in 
    place_configure + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".37362480.37388656"
```

Code of the class:

```
from tkinter import Label, StringVar
from tkinter import ttk


class MainGui():

    def __init__(self, main_frame, avaliable_directories):
        """
        Building main elements located in the main_frame.

        Args:
            main_frame: instance - module Tkinter class ttk.Frame.
            avaliable_directories: dict - contains avaliable directories for back up.
        """

        self.main_frame = main_frame
        self.avaliable_directories = avaliable_directories

        self.choose_backup_dir_name = StringVar()
        self.style_1 = ttk.Style()
        self.style_1.map('directory.TButton',
             foreground=[('!disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(0, 0, 0)), ('disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(115, 115, 115))],
             background=[('!disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(40, 240, 240)), ('disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(240, 240, 240))])

        self.pagination = 1
        self.button_directories = []
        self.active_directories = []

        for element in self.avaliable_directories:
            temp = ttk.Button(
                self.main_frame,
                width=20,
                style='directory.TButton',
                text=element
                )
            self.button_directories.append(temp)

        if len(self.button_directories) > 20:
            self.go_back = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, width=2, text='<')
            self.go_back.place(x=325, y=540)
            self.go_back.bind('<Button-1>', self.go_back_event_handler)

            self.go_forward = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, width=2, text='>')
            self.go_forward.place(x=350, y=540)
            self.go_forward.bind('<Button-1>', self.go_forward_event_handler)

        self.show_avaliable_directories()

    # Interesting part starts here.
    def show_avaliable_directories(self):
        for i, element in enumerate(self.button_directories[20*(self.pagination-1):20*self.pagination]):# Implementation of pagination.
            _x = 20+200*(i//10)
            _y = 20+40*(i%10)
            element.place(x=_x, y=_y)
            # Placed elements are assigned to new list.
            # When discarded (bellow) all elements from the list are destroyed.
            self.active_directories.append(element)

    def clear_active_directories(self):
        for element in self.active_directories:
            element.destroy()
        self.active_directories = []

    def go_back_event_handler(self, event):
        if self.pagination > 1:
            self.pagination -= 1
            self.clear_active_directories()
            self.show_avaliable_directories()

    def go_forward_event_handler(self, event):
        limit = (len(self.button_directories)//20)+1 
        if self.pagination < limit:
            self.pagination += 1
            self.clear_active_directories()
            self.show_avaliable_directories()
```

I have no clue why it works when I increase the page number, but it does not when I try to decrease the page number. Thanks for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found crude answer. Each time the program displays new Buttons the list of all elements (Buttons) is created. When the page is changed now the program destroys all elements in the list even unused ones. This may not be effective but works.

```
from tkinter import Label, StringVar
from tkinter import ttk


class MainGui():

    def __init__(self, main_frame, avaliable_directories):
        """
        Building main elements located in the main_frame.

        Args:
            main_frame: instance - module Tkinter class ttk.Frame.
            avaliable_directories: dict - contains avaliable directories for back up.
        """

        self.main_frame = main_frame
        self.avaliable_directories = avaliable_directories

        self.choose_backup_dir_name = StringVar()
        self.style_1 = ttk.Style()
        self.style_1.map('directory.TButton',
            foreground=[('!disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(0, 0, 0)), ('disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(115, 115, 115))],
            background=[('!disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(40, 240, 240)), ('disabled', '#%02x%02x%02x' %(240, 240, 240))])

        self.pagination = 1
        self.button_directories = []

        if len(self.avaliable_directories) > 20:
            self.go_back = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, width=2, text='<')
            self.go_back.place(x=325, y=540)
            self.go_back.bind('<Button-1>', self.go_back_event_handler)

            self.go_forward = ttk.Button(self.main_frame, width=2, text='>')
            self.go_forward.place(x=350, y=540)
            self.go_forward.bind('<Button-1>', self.go_forward_event_handler)

        self.show_avaliable_directories()

    def show_avaliable_directories(self):
        for element in self.avaliable_directories:
            temp = ttk.Button(
                self.main_frame,
                width=20,
                style='directory.TButton',
                text=element
                )
            self.button_directories.append(temp)

        for i, element in enumerate(self.button_directories[20*(self.pagination-1):20*self.pagination]):
            _x = 20+200*(i//10)
            _y = 20+40*(i%10)
            element.place(x=_x, y=_y)

    def clear_active_directories(self):
        for element in self.button_directories:
            element.destroy()
        self.button_directories = []

    def go_back_event_handler(self, event):
        if self.pagination > 1:
            self.pagination -= 1
            self.clear_active_directories()
            self.show_avaliable_directories()

    def go_forward_event_handler(self, event):
        limit = (len(self.button_directories)//20)+1 
        if self.pagination < limit:
            self.pagination += 1
            self.clear_active_directories()
            self.show_avaliable_directories()
```